# Power transistor or voltage regulator as alternative to rheostat

Tags: voltage-regulator, rheostat

I need to modulate the voltage to a 100 watt 12 Volt DC vacuum pump. I bought some potentiometers before realizing that the wattage they were rated for was too low, and that I needed a proper 100 watt rheostat. However, these components are quite costly, so I wonder if I can use a power transistor or some other component to modulate the voltage and control it via the potentiometer as a cost saving option.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the vacuum pump and/or its motor?

Comment: Have a look for an introductory article on PWM (pulse width modulation).

Comment: odd as it may seem, running a pump motor at lower than it's rated voltage can actually cause it to burn out. Are you sure you want a lower voltage?

Comment: *so I wonder if I can use a power transistor or some other component to modulate the voltage and control it via the potentiometer as a cost saving option.* I suggest forgetting about that. Is your pump running on mains AC? Like 240 V or 120 V AC. Motors running on that are not easy and often even **impossible** to control. There are ways to do this with suitable motors and special control boxes but those are **expensive**. Trying to do this "on the cheap" is very likely to end in **smoke and fire** so be warned. Take the advise above, use the pump as it is now.

Comment: the pump is 12 volt DC

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy: " running a pump motor at lower than ~~it's~~ [*its] rated voltage can actually cause it to burn out". I haven't heard that. Please explain. Is it because it tends to stall and stay stalled?

Comment: It might be simpler to use a pressure regulator and let the pump run at full speed.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Electric motors tend to draw more current at lower speeds. They are designed to withstand that extra current for a short period, as they are spinning up to their rated speed -- but for a short period only, typically 30 seconds. Making your motor struggle to pump by giving it insufficient voltage may cause high currents and burn out.

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy: "Electric motors tend to draw more current at lower speeds. " Yes, _at a given voltage_. But OP is not slowing down a motor while retaining the same supply voltage. Instead, OP is reducing the voltage. Therefore, I fail to understand your statement that "running a pump motor at lower than [*its] rated voltage can actually cause it to burn out."

Comment: @DavideAndrea, again, lower voltage may cause higher currents unless the load is reduced. Brownout's causing motor failure is discussed in here --> https://www.plantservices.com/articles/2004/437/

Comment: Thank you for the reference about AC motors. As here we are talking about DC motors, would you happen to have a reference that states that under-volted DC motors may burn out?

Comment: @DavideAndrea you can read this thread https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/dc-motor-burns-out-at-low-voltage.280934/ not exactly a reference, and not every answer is reliable.

Comment: Thank you, @Math Keeps Me Busy. I also [asked in Reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/Motors/comments/q2u0dc/is_an_undervolted_dc_motor_more_likely_to_burn_out/) and someone suggested that a DC motor with a fan could overheat at low speeds.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130305/discussion-between-math-keeps-me-busy-and-davide-andrea).

Answer (score 1):

As I am sure you already have guessed, the industry already has a ready-made solution to regulate the speed of a motor (such as those used in pumps). Therefore, there is no need to reinvent the wheel with a "power transistor or voltage regulator".

You don't say, but I will assume that you have a DC pump.

For pumps with a DC motor, we use a "Motor controller", also knows as an ESC (Electronic Speed Controller). For example, for a 12 Vdc motor: https://www.amazon.com/12v-dc-motor-speed-controller/s?k=12v+dc+motor+speed+controller

Comment: yes I have a 12 volt DC pump

Comment: so i do not need to worry about undervoltage over heating when using PWM to the pump since the PWM is always at 12 volts and it is basically just being switched on and off ? does repeatedly coming on or off wear the motor out faster ?